# Configuration of Ubuntu to my computer

Tags: system-installation

I am trying to load ubuntu onto my computer from a USB disc drive and the error message I'm receiving is: No configuration file found. How do I fix this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Assuming that you mean 'installing' by 'load', how did you make your thumb drive bootable?

Answer (score 0):

I think [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) may help you solve your problem or, at least, help you tell us what you need ;)

Please, provide some information about your steps and the hardware you're using.